# Tell RubyGems to always search remote gems

Tags: ruby, search, rubygems

is there a way to tell rubygems to always search for remote gems (instead of local)? I tried adding the following line to my `~/.gemrc`

```
gem: --remote
```

but the problem is, that when i do `gem list` i get the following result

```
~$ gem list

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

- (1)
10io-jekyll (0.7.0)
1234567890_ (1.0)
2Performant (0.0.8)
360_services (1.1.3)
3scale_client (2.2.4)
4info (2.0.0)
6twenty-google_translate (0.0.4)
7digital (0.0.2)
…
```

this means that *all* gem commands now assume that i want to work with remote gems, which isnt exactly what i want to do. can i somehow restrict the `--remote` option to only apply to the `gem search` command?

thanks for your answers,
patrick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add:

```
search: --remote
```

to your `.gemrc` file it defaults to that parameter just for that command.